# How to save an image/screenshot with adobe air in a webpage to client's machine? by passing the mouseclick or keyboard input

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, augmented-reality, screen-capture

I have been working on an AR app for a few hours and have done it well, its performing perfect my machine, but when I am trying to save the picture of screen or screenshot on a webpage, the demo page of my app, It just don't function.

I have used the JPGEncoder and it seems as if it is not doing anything and after the time given for photograph to be taken nothing works other than the camera.

Edit,
The code was not working because of my desired functionality of, clicking a pic when user have his hand over the camera button, adobe has restricted this for securoty reasons, I tried the 
dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.CLICK));

but can't get through.

Any help on, how to save screenshot on user's machine without mouseclick or keyboard interaction.

Thanks
Saurabh

Comment: So is it AIR or is it FP? How do you take the screenshot? What do you want to do? To upload it? Or to save it on the user's PC? You mention both... What does the camera has to do with it? If you want help, you have to be more precise with your question.

Comment: It is air, I am taking screenshot of my app with bytearray + bitmapdata and than using the JPEGEncoder class, I wish it to be saved on user's PC. Camera feed is the background of app, I am making a virtual dressing room and want the user to have a selfie with the new dress he/she is trying.. That's it

Comment: I have tried both File and FileReference class but none seems to work for me

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason. It is not possible to save a webcam or screen shot without user interaction like mouse click or keyboard event.

What I did was, save the bitmapdata and display it with a button to download the the image and now a user gets the preview also before image saved on his hard disk.

Now, when a user clicks on this download button, we get the desired user interaction and adobe now allows to save the image.